# Derivatives of Exponential and Logarithmic Functions Unit Assignment HELPPPP

Tags: calculus

> The percentage $p$ of people who have switched to a new social network y years after it was
>   introduced is modelled by the function
>   $$
> P=\frac{100}{1+9e^{-y}}
> $$
>   a. What percentage of the population switched immediately?
>
> b. How long did it take before 75% of the population had switched?
>
> c. After how many years was the new network growing the fastest?
>
> d. Using Curve Sketching methods, sketch the graph of the function. Make sure that you
>   include all steps, charts, and derivations details.
>
> e. Give a possible explanation for the shape of the curve.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried? Also please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I attached a picture of my work done so far. I'm not sure if my first derivative is correct or not for 2c.

Comment: You made a mistake in the b-part. The equation
$$
\frac{100}{75} (= \frac{4}{3}) = 1+ 9e^{-y}
$$
is correct, but do the next line again. And be careful when you **divide** both sides by 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (b) part is incorrect. Here, the answer is $\ln(27)$. Check your steps again, you forgot to subtract $1$ from LHS after reducing $100/75$ to $4/3$. Further, the proper solution to the first one would be finding out $\frac{p(0)}{p(a)}\cdot 100$ as $a$ tends to infinity.

Comment: oh yes thanks for pointing that out I fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For a. think of when y=0

For c. use calculus to find the fastest rate of change

For graph sketching try to use a standardised method: Finding x,y intercepts, stationary points, asymptotes, graph behavior by taking limits (if there are any)

Comment: For c) do I just find the first derivative, set it equal to zero and find my time?

Comment: You want to find the fastest growing rate. The growing rate is the derivative, and therefore you want to find when the second derivative is zero. (Notice also that the first derivative is never zero)

Comment: ok makes sense, basically finding the point of inflection